# Search match to autofill text inputs google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to do a match and return function: search barcode and a size value in a sheet, and add it to a textbox in a sidebar
something went wrong - script do not return any values

```
  var barcodeBox = document.getElementById("bcdn");
  var typeBox = document.getElementById("stype");
  var sizeBox = document.getElementById("size");

  document.getElementById("butn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
  document.getElementById("bcdn").addEventListener("input",getStype);


  function getStype(){

    var bCode = document.getElementById("bcdn").value;

    if(bCode.length === 10){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSize).getSize(bCode);

    
    }else{
      document.getElementById("size").value = "-";
      M.updateTextFields();
    } // end Else
  } // end getStype

  function updateSize(size){
    
    document.getElementById("size").value = size;
    M.updateTextFields();

  }
```

this is gs code

```
function getSize(bCode){

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Barcode List");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var bCodeList = data.map(function(r){return[0];});
  var sizeList = data.map(function(r){return[1];});

  var position = bCodeList.indexOf(bCode);
  if(position > -1){
    return sizeList[position].toFixed(2);
  }else{
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: where is the variable sizecode.

Answer (score 0):

`bCode` seems to be just a value but `bCodeList` is an array of arrays so `bCodeList.indexOf(bCode)` is probably always going to be -1

Maybe change this `var bCodeList = data.map(function(r){return[0];});`
to this `var bCodeList = data.map(r => 0);`

Of course sizeList has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Missing get spreadsheet
2. Wrong return of `map`
3. Not converting `[][]` into `[]` for `indexOf`

```js
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Barcode List");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var bCodeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0];}).flat();
  var sizeList = data.map(function(r){return r[1];}).flat();
```